# How subcarrier affects MCS in NBIoT Uplink communication?

Tags: communication

I cannot find it in the newer 3GPP docs. So...

To calculate Transport Block Size we this use:

[image: TBS Table]

> Note: I TBS = MCS

But I found that if we use only one sub-carrier (single-tone) in NB1 we cannot use 11 and 12 MCS.

> Mapping between the MCS index, the resource units and the TBSin bits
>   for uplink transmission. For single-tone transmission, MCS indices 11
>   and 12 are not used. [47]

47 redirect me to

> 3GPP,  “TS  36.213Physical  layer  procedures”,  version 
>   13.3.0,November2016.  [Online].  Available: http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/WiVsSpec--690063.htm.

But how about category NB2? They added 13 MCS. Is it omitted too? Or maybe they moved line from 11,12 to 12,13?